# Steam not running under WINE after Linux Mint restart

Tags: wine, steam, playonlinux

So yesterday I downloaded Windows Steam and installed and ran it under WINE for all my games that aren't native to Linux, well, I shut down my PC for the night and wake up, try to launch Steam (both manually and through PlayOnLinux) and it wouldn't launch. It still works with all the other programs I have installed under WINE such as 7Zip and CPU-Z. The native Linux version of Steam works fine. Any idea how to fix this or what's going on?

Edit: It worked fine before the reboot.

Comment: Please try launching it from a terminal to see if there are any error messages. If there are, [edit] your question and include them.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I found the issue. Steam had read-only permissions... Any way to make it always have permissions? Edit: I take that back, the shortcut is broken, not steams permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my shortcut just wasn't working, so if your Steam in WINE wont launch, find Steam.exe in the steam folder and launch it from there.